# Adding a particle effect to armor stands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I want to create a armor stand that contains some particles like fireworks. How would I do something like this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `/particle` command creates particle effects. Its full syntax is:

```
/particle <name> <x> <y> <z> <xd> <yd> <zd> <speed> [count] [mode] [player] [extra parameters]
```

You can type `/particle` then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to see a list of available particles.

To have armor stands play the particle, you will need to combine this with `/execute`:

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand] ~ ~ ~ /particle fireworksSpark ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 1 1
```

This makes all `ArmorStand`s (change to `armor_stand` in 1.11 onwards) create a `fireworksSpark` particle at themselves (`~ ~ ~`) at a speed of `1`.

If you want to play this continuously, you will need to put this command in a repeating command block.

`<xd> <yd> <zd>` refers to particle spread; you can change this to change how far away from the origin that particles will appear.

Comment: Alright so the first part works. Im confused on how to play it continuously. Can i get an example?

Comment: @Matt You can give yourself a command block with `/give @p command_block`. Place it down and copy paste in the command. Then, using the buttons along the bottom, change it from `Impulse` to `Repeating`, then give it redstone power (e.g: a lever).

Comment: Ah okay. But what about the commands? Im confused on the formatting ( <xd> and so on. And would it also keep on repeating until the power is taken away?

Comment: The command you should have repeating is `/execute @e[type=ArmorStand] ~ ~ ~ /particle fireworksSpark ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 1 1`. It will keep repeating until power is taken away.